# Namespace in partial class

Tags: c#, class, refactoring

I have a public partial class called Repository and I have refactored the method over multiple files, just to get a better overview. In general, I have the same method for every object like below :

- GetObjects
- GetObject
- SetObject
- DeleteObject

The project is growing and while the code is clean, when I type Get for the methods in my code, I get a list of more then 40 options, while the object is to get only the most important one.

So I call the `var objects = repository.GetObjects();` to retrieve all the objects, but is it maybe possible to write it as : `var objects = repository.Object.GetAll();`.

And then of course the Object is the name of the different objects, like User, Relation, Address etc.

Hope to hear if this is possible and if so, how?

Comment: Isn't `Object` just a property of the repository type, and a child class actually contains the methods?

Comment: If you have to split your methods over multiple files, I wouldn't consider the code as _clean_. Having multiple `Get*` etc methods doing the same violates the DRY principle. Have you considered generics? Like `GetItem<T>()`, `GetItems<T>()`, `DeleteItem<T>()` etc?

Comment: It's a bit hard to give advice since we don't know your code base/context. Maybe check out this [repository pattern tutorial from Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and just see if any of ideas there would be of help?